# Quick Question About DNS Spoofing popular/non-popular sites

Tags: dns

Earlier I'm having a difficult time spoofing DNS to my own computer. I'm using ettercap to arp poison the target. I've had nothing but success. But I've noticed that I can only spoof non-popular websites or web gaming sites. However, I'll try to spoof more popular services like facebook.com or even the unrealengine forums I go to with no luck. It will always say "This page can not be displayed." This will happen even after I flush the system cache, browser cache and all my private data in IE on my target computer. After some Googling and even searching this board, I've seen that SSL with HSTS may be a factor. This does not make sense to me. If I killed the browsers memory, how would IE know facebook even uses SSL if it shouldn't be able to get to facebook in the first place? Do modern browsers have some kind of list of domain/IP relationships to check against? If so, then how do all the Youtube tutorials do it so well? Did they do something off camera to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do modern browsers have some kind of list of domain/IP relationships to check against

Yes. Modern browsers have a builtin list of important sites using HSTS which protect even a fresh browser installation against hijacking of these sites with sslstrip or similar. See [the chromium source code](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/net/http/transport_security_state_static.json) for the list of sites protected this way by Chromium and derivatives (Chrome, Opera...) and at https://hstspreload.appspot.com/ you even propose your own site to get added.